# uWSGI + Django: ImportError: No module named 'wsgi'

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

My project structure:

`/srv/venv` is the home of virtualenv (contains directories like `bin` or `lib`)

`/srv/venv/webapp` is the home of the Django application and contains the file `wsgi.py`

My `.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python
chdir = /srv/venv/webapp
module = wsgi
home = /srv/venv/
master = true
processes = 10
socket = /tmp/srv.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
buffer-size = 32767
die-on-term = true
```

Upon startup, uWSGI says:

```
Wed Jul  4 10:58:40 2018 - chdir() to /srv/venv/webapp
Wed Jul  4 10:58:40 2018 - Set PythonHome to /srv/venv/
ImportError: No module named 'wsgi'
```

And every request ends up with:

```
Wed Jul  4 10:28:45 2018 - --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 643|app: -1|req: -1/1] 192.168.33.1 () {42 vars in 653 bytes} [Wed Jul  4 10:28:45 2018] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

When I do `cd /srv/venv/webapp`, run python and type `import wsgi`, no errors happen.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**UPDATE:** When I install and run uWSGI from the virtualenv (`/srv/venv/bin/uwsgi`), everything works fine. But why it is not working with system-wide uWSGI?

**UPDATE2:** I wrote a systemd service to run uWSGI at startup and it is not working again - same error. It starts working after I do `systemctl restart uwsgi` manually. Adding a 10 seconds delay did not solve it. I ran out of ideas.

Comment: What does your wsgi.py look like? Please add to the question.

Comment: `import os`

`from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application`

`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")`

`application = get_wsgi_application()`

Comment: Ok, see the answer below.  In your uwsgi.ini update it to module = wsgi:application

Comment: still not working, but see the update

Comment: You can use uwsgi -H /srv/venv  

Which tells uwsgi which virtualenv to use, https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python.html#virtualenv-support

Comment: still did not manage to do that :( please see the update

Comment: It's turned into a different question, if you now have it manually working without the ImportError (which it sounds like you do) then it's potentially more of a systemd question which will require seeing the systemd service file you have created.  If this is the case close this question and start a new one.

Comment: I think I already managed to find a solution, the actual problem was that the `wsgi.py` file is in a directory which is mounted from NFS and it seems to take some time and so at the start of uWSGI, the directory was not ready yet...but your answers might still be useful for the others, so thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wsgi.py looks something like this:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Your uwsgi.ini needs to be updated to:

```
module = wsgi:application
```

You can also add this in the uwsgi.ini to specify your virtual env:

```
virtualenv = /path/to/you/virtualenv
```